# f:ajax does not update ui:repeat

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, uirepeat

My JSF page is like this, The `<f:ajax>` part does now work.

```
<h:selectOneListbox value="#{category.categoryId}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{category.allSubCategories}" var="c" itemLabel="#{c.title}" itemValue="#{c.categoryId}" />
    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="projects" />
</h:selectOneListbox>

<h:panelGroup id="projects">
    <ul>
        <ui:repeat items="#{category.allItems}" var="o" id="itemTable">
            <li><h:graphicImage value="#{o.imageUrl}" id="itemImage" /></li>
            <li><h:outputText value="#{o.title}" /></li>
            <li><label>Price: $ </label><h:outputText value="#{o.price}" /></li>
        </ui:repeat>
    </ul>       
</h:panelGroup>
```

My bean is:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "category")
@SessionScoped
public class CategoryServiceBean extends BaseService implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -12082902292711980L;    
    private Integer categoryId;
    private Integer parentCategoryId;
    private Integer locationId;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{categorySupport}")
    private CategorySupport categorySupport;

    public List<RestCategory> getAllSubCategories() {
        return getCategorySupport().getCategoriesByParent(locationId, parentCategoryId);            
    }

    public List<RestItem> getAllItems() {
        return response = getCategorySupport().getCategoryItems( locationId, categoryId);               
    }

    // ...
}
```

My problem is that the `<f:ajax execute="@form" render="projects" />` does not populate values to `<h:panelGroup id="projects">`. How is this caused and how can I solve it? If I use `<h:dataTable>` instead of `<ui:repeat>`, then it works fine.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use a listener in the ajax of yours and inside the listener populate a proper value inside the allItems (move the logic from allItems getter inside the listener code) , then try...

Comment: Please don't tag `[ajax4jsf]` if you aren't using [Ajax4jsf](http://jboss.org/richfaces) at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ui:repeat items="#{category.allItems}" var="o" id="itemTable">
```

The `items` attribute doesn't exist in [`<ui:repeat>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html). You're apparently confusing it with [`<c:forEach>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/c/forEach.html). Use the `value` attribute.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{category.allItems}" var="o" id="itemTable">
```